# Is there safe way to resolve component from Castle.Windsor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, castle-windsor

I have my implementation of ControllerFactory for handling constructor injection in controllers, however I want to use default way to resolve controllers in case if some of them are not registered:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
    public WindsorControllerFactory(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but I really would like to avoid exceptions

Comment: Why would some controllers not be registered in your container?

Comment: Maybe it's wrong, but I want to register in container only controllers with parameterized constructors, not all of them.

Comment: And what would be the advantage of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `container.Kernel.HasComponent(Type type)`:

```
bool isRegistered;
var container = new WindsorContainer();

isRegistered = container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(IFoo));
Console.WriteLine(isRegistered);

container.Register(Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>());
isRegistered = container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(IFoo));
Console.WriteLine(isRegistered);
```

This outputs:

```
False
True
```